# My recursive attempt at Collatz Sequence in Python

Tags: python, recursion, collatz-sequence

```
def collatz(n, counter):
    if n == 1:
        return counter
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return collatz(n/2, counter + 1)
    else:
        return collatz(3*n + 1, counter + 1)

print(int(collatz(15, 0)))
```

Is there any way to improve this code? The two arguments passed on the `collatz()` function rubs me the wrong way. Tells me that should only be one, but I don't know better.

My question is an attempt to improving my Python vocabulary as I just barely started. So, what useful Python tool could I have used here to make the code better?

Comment: Do Python implementations typically eliminate tail-calls?  If not, you're heading for a stack overflow by using recursion...

Comment: @TobySpeight CPython, the reference implementation, doesn't perform any form of tail call elimination

Comment: See https://tobiaskohn.ch/index.php/2018/08/28/optimising-python-3/ for more information @TobySpeight

Comment: @Jasmijn: It's not just CPython. Guido van Rossum has said that *NO* Python implementation is allowed to eliminate tail calls. So, any implementation that eliminates tail calls is non-compliant, and thus *by definition* not a Python implementation. Therefore, it is impossible that there is a Python implementation that eliminates tail calls, because if it did, it wouldn't be a Python implementation. (Personally, I find that quite insane: not eliminating tail calls is essentially a memory leak, so why would you *force* implementors to leak memory?)

Comment: @JörgWMittag Where do you store traceback information if TCO is allowed? In another stack? Isn't the point that tracebacks are more important than allowing you to use recursion to loop? If you need such levels of recursion you can normally quite easily convert away from an FP approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Formatting / Spacing**

There should be spaces around operators, such as `n / 2` or `3 * n`. Some IDEs can handle this for you through an auto-formatting option (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> for PyCharm on Windows).

---

**Type hints**

It's useful to provide type hints for arguments and function return values. This increases readability and allows for easier and better error checking. Refer to [PEP484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) for more information.

```
def collatz(n: int, counter: int) -> int:
    # function body here
```

---

**Return values**

Adding these type hints will help us identify the first improvement. As the Collatz sequence only contains integers, our `collatz` function should only take an integer as the `n` argument. `collatz(n / 2, counter + 1)` passes a float, so to keep it consistent we should probably convert it to an `int` before passing it: `collatz(int(n / 2), counter + 1)`. Even better, we can use the floor division operator `//`: `collatz(n // 2, counter + 1)`

Please note that you do not need to convert the function output to an `int`, as it will only ever return an `int` value.

---

**Default arguments**

There are multiple approaches to improving the handling of the `counter` argument, which rubs you the wrong way. This is good intuition on your part. With default arguments, Python offers one really concise option:

```
def collatz(n: int, counter: int = 0) -> int:
    if n == 1:
        return counter
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return collatz(n // 2, counter + 1)
    else:
        return collatz(3 * n + 1, counter + 1)
```

As you can see, the only addition we need to implement is `counter = 0`, which makes `0` the default argument for `counter`. This means that `counter` will be set to `0` if the argument is not provided by the caller.

You can now simply call

```
print(collatz(15))
```

More on [default arguments in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-arguments-in-python/).

Comment: I would also recommend using `cache` from `itertools`, it will dramatically speed up the code.

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar I agree, good recommendation!

Comment: The type hints are certainly useful, and I definitely miss it coming from C. Do Python programmers regularly use them? Or is it something that goes away when you're already comfortable using Python?
The `counter` variable initialization was my problem; I could not find where it should be put. And so my solution was just to pass it to the function. I know that's not how it should be because I admit my Python knowledge is still very limited. 
You provided me with easy-to-understand explanations. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help! I'd say type hints are useful at any level of Python proficiency, as they allow for easier debugging and maintainability. They do probably provide the biggest benefit to beginner and intermediate Pythonistas though =)

Comment: Btw why do we care about keeping track of `counter`?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar the goal of the code is to print the length of the collatz sequence. Could you elaborate as to why you asked? I have a beginner understanding of Python, and just programming in general (never touched a DSA topic before).

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: Because testing the Collatz conjecture isn't just about infinite loop or not; counting the iterations is interesting.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Empirical_data / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Visualizations.  (Besides visualizations, results may provide some insight into algorithmic optimizations to short-circuit the basic steps; see various answers on [Why does C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture run faster than hand-written assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40354978) that focus on the algorithm instead of asm)

Comment: (Although I think you already know that based on your comments on your own answer;  maybe I misunderstood what you were asking.  Maybe you meant why we want a 2nd arg at all, when your answer shows a way to do it with non-tail calls where the eventual count just ends up in a return value.  That's good too, but defeats tail-call optimization for languages / implementations that can do that.)

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken Python doesn't actually have function overloading, usually it's faked with default arguments or some `*args` trickery. Maybe make that more clear?

Comment: @PeterCordes your second comment hit the nail right on the head about the meaning of my comment. I wrote it in the middle of an lecture, so I had to keep it brief. I elaborated as you said when I got home in my answer =)

Comment: @ToddSewell Thanks for your comment, I cleared it up. That's what happens when you edit previously working code while writing the answer without re-running it.

Answer (score 15):

#### Sequence vs counting

As stated in the comments

> the goal of the code is to print the length of the Collatz sequence. Could you elaborate as to why you asked?

As OP mentions, he is *not* interested in the sequence itself, but its *length*. As such we actually do not need the values from the sequence itself. We *only* need to count how many iterations it takes to reach 1. The following code does precisely that: every time the function is called we increment by one:

```
def collatz(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + collatz(n // 2)
    else:  # n % 2 == 1:
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1)
```

Spend some time thinking about this. Recursion is *hard*. Go through the code above by hand for the number 5 and see what it returns and how. As a minor point, it is better to be explicit than implicit in Python. Compare

```
if n == 1:
    return n
```

vs

```
if n == 1:
    return 1
```

While trivial, it is a good mindset to get into.

#### Cache

It can be very wise to cache previous calls to the function to save time. Assume we try to calculate `collatz(23)`:

```
23, 70, 35, 106, 53, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1
```

So `collatz(23) = 15`. Now assume we want to calculate `collatz(61)`:

```
 61, 184, 92, 46, (23)
```

Notice how we stop early: `23` is already saved so we only have to do 4 iterations instead of 19. This can, for instance, be implemented as follows:

```
cache = {1: 0}

def collatz(n: int) -> int:
    if n in cache:
        return cache[n]
    else:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            m = n // 2
        else:
            m = 3 * n + 1
        res = collatz(m) + 1
        cache[n] = res
        return res
```

However. there are builtins for handling [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) in Python.
Introducing the decorator [`itertools.cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache).

```
import functools


@functools.cache
def collatz(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + collatz(n // 2)
    else:  # n % 2 == 1:
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1)
```

Let us add a test function to benchmark how much quicker our function is with memoization:

```
def longest_collatz(limit: int) -> int:
    longest = 0
    for i in range(1, limit):
        current = collatz(i)
        if current > longest:
            longest = current
    return longest


def main():
    limit = 10 ** 4
    with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
        longest_collatz(limit)

    stats = pstats.Stats(pr)
    stats.strip_dirs()
    stats.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.CALLS)
    stats.print_stats()
```

Here we simply compare how many function calls it takes to find the longest Collatz sequence amongst the first 10 000 numbers. I wanted to try with higher values but your version took too long to complete...

```
859639 function calls (10002 primitive calls) in 12.444 seconds
 21667 function calls ( 4330 primitive calls) in  0.332 seconds
```

Of course it is much smarter to just iterate over the odd values, but this is just for comparison. To compare the versions I just commented  the `@functools.cache` bit.

#### Full code

```
import functools
import cProfile
import pstats

@functools.cache
def collatz(n: int) -> int:
    if n == 1:
        return n
    elif n % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + collatz(n // 2)
    else:  # n % 2 == 1:
        return 1 + collatz(3 * n + 1)

def longest_collatz(limit: int) -> int:
    longest = 0
    for i in range(1, limit):
        current = collatz(i)
        if current > longest:
            longest = current
    return longest

def main():
    limit = 10 ** 4
    with cProfile.Profile() as pr:
        longest_collatz(limit)

    stats = pstats.Stats(pr)
    stats.strip_dirs()
    stats.sort_stats(pstats.SortKey.CALLS)
    stats.print_stats()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I could imagine it would be an awesome feeling to go back to this answer when I can finally understand every concept you put here. I highly appreciate how you optimized the code and explained it in a way that's not daunting. The runtime data is the icing on the cake. Thank you :)

Comment: Note that we could have done this _even_ faster if our goal was not to generate the length of the sequence, but the longest one. I wrote some bad (but super fast) code for solving this a bunch of years ago https://github.com/Oisov/Project-Euler/blob/master/Problems/PE_014/Python/PE_014.py. In python 2, but it can easily be rewritten. The next step up after understanding this answer, is understanding this code. The final step is improving the code with typing hints, doctests and proper docstring + comments.

Comment: As a final comment the github link also avoids the _tail call recursion_ issue by simply implementing a iterative instead of recursive version =)